# Changing elements' CSS using jQuery after another element is changed with AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ajax, shopify

I have a custom button in the a header next to a "cart" link. Website uses AJAX cart. When an item is added to cart, the cart link enlarges to include nr of items in cart. This causes the cart link to overflow and overlap the custom button next to it. Essentially what I'm trying to achieve is to add a margin to the custom button when an item is added to cart and the cart link is expanded. My first thought was to wrap both in a div and use CSS flex to adjust the sizing of both, however, and please correct me if I'm wrong, I thought it would be quicker to just write a script that would add a margin to my custom button. Definitely didn't turn out to be the quicker way as I've been stuck on it for hours now - any help would be greatly appreciated. I've browsed through similar posts and couldn't find a result that I want - any help would be greatly appreciated (I'm still new to JS and jQuery but learning). Below is the code and some of the things that I've tried.

```
HTML - header

      <div class="header--menu">
        
                     <div class="custom-btn-container">
        <a href="/apps/quick-shop/" class="custom-button">Quick Order</a>
        </div>

        
        {%
          render 'framework--x-menu',
          js_class: 'XMenu',
          align: menu_alignment,
          overlap_parent: 1,
          handle: menu
        %}
      </div>
    {% endif %}
    


    <div class="header--cart">
      {% render 'snippet-cart', cart_icon: cart_icon %}
    </div>
    

  </div>
```

```
HTML - cart

{% if settings.cart--type == 'drawer' %}
  <div
    class="cart--open-right off-canvas--open"
    data-off-canvas--open="right-sidebar"
    data-off-canvas--view="cart"
    aria-haspopup=”menu”
  >
{% endif %}

<a
  class="header--cart-link"
  data-item="accent-text"
  href="{{ routes.cart_url }}"
  aria-label="{{ 'layout.header.cart' | t }}"
>

  {% if cart_icon == 'text' %}
    {{ 'layout.header.cart' | t }}
  {% elsif cart_icon == 'bag' %}
    {% render 'framework--icons', icon: 'bag' %}
  {% else %}
    {% render 'framework--icons', icon: 'cart' %}
  {% endif %}

  <span class="header--cart-number" data-item-count="{{ cart.item_count }}">
  (<span class="cart--external--total-items">{{ cart.item_count }}</span>)
  </span>
</a>

{% if settings.cart--type == 'drawer' %}
  </div>
{% endif %}
```

And these are some of the scripts that I've tried:

```
    window.onload = () => {
        if (jQuery('.header--cart-number').data('item-count') != '0') {
            $(".custom-button").css('margin-right', '10px');
        }
    }
```

The above is nearly what I'm after, but only works after refreshing the page.

```
    document.ajaxComplete = () => {
        if (jQuery('.header--cart-number').data('item-count') != '0') {
            $(".custom-button").css('margin-right', '10px');
        }
    }
```

similar story

```
    $(document).ajaxSuccess(function() {
        if (jQuery('.header--cart-number').data('item-count') != '0') {
            $(".custom-button").css('margin-right', '10px');
        }
    }
```

This didn't do anything whatsoever.

I'm sure I'm missing something small, but it's driving me mad. Again, any help will be greatly appreciated!

Best,
J

Comment: where is your ajax call code ?

Comment: You need to post the temp or permanent link of the website where the actual issue, from code it is harder to provide and solution.